# Safari - THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: ERROR: unsupported shader version1: #version 300 es

Tags: three.js, safari, shader, webgl, aframe

We have a new problem that has just appeared in Safari.

Aframe Text is no longer rendering in Safari with this error. The shader I think it is refering to is the Three.Meshline shader, which is rendering fine in the scene.

Renders fine on all other browsers, anyone know what has changed!?

```
Error] THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  – 1282 – "35715" – false – "gl.getProgramInfoLog" – "" (2)
"THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex
ERROR: unsupported shader version1: #version 300 es
2: in vec2 uv;
3: in vec3 position;
4: uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
5: uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
6: out vec2 vUV;
7: void main(void) {
8:   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
9:   vUV = uv;
10: }"
"THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
ERROR: unsupported shader version1: #version 300 es
2: precision highp float;
3: uniform bool negate;
4: uniform float alphaTest;
5: uniform float opacity;
6: uniform sampler2D map;
7: uniform vec3 color;
8: in vec2 vUV;
9: out vec4 fragColor;
10: float median(float r, float g, float b) {
11:   return max(min(r, g), min(max(r, g), b));
12: }
13: #define BIG_ENOUGH 0.001
14: #define MODIFIED_ALPHATEST (0.02 * isBigEnough / BIG_ENOUGH)
15: void main() {
16:   vec3 sampleColor = texture(map, vUV).rgb;
17:   if (negate) { sampleColor = 1.0 - sampleColor; }
18:   float sigDist = median(sampleColor.r, sampleColor.g, sampleColor.b) - 0.5;
19:   float alpha = clamp(sigDist / fwidth(sigDist) + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
20:   float dscale = 0.353505;
21:   vec2 duv = dscale * (dFdx(vUV) + dFdy(vUV));
22:   float isBigEnough = max(abs(duv.x), abs(duv.y));
23:   // Do modified alpha test.
24:   if (isBigEnough > BIG_ENOUGH) {
25:     float ratio = BIG_ENOUGH / isBigEnough;
26:     alpha = ratio * alpha + (1.0 - ratio) * (sigDist + 0.5);
27:   }
28:   // Do modified alpha test.
29:   if (alpha < alphaTest * MODIFIED_ALPHATEST) { discard; return; }
30:   fragColor = vec4(color.xyz, alpha * opacity);
31: }"
```

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce a very simple demo with the bug that uses `THREE.Meshline` so we can take a look at what could be causing it? You could use JSFiddle, or create [a code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) I don't think Meshline is a standard class in Three.js, is it from a third-party module?

Comment: it's a problem with latest Aframe

Answer (score -1):

Problem in latest Aframe. Reverted to last stable and it went away.